# Detectando clique em elementos de um array

Tags: javascript, array, tooltip

Se eu possuo uma `div` com `id="banner-tooltips"`, e dentro dela tenho ***n*** `<span>` tags declaradas em variáveis com javascript, como consigo detectar o clique individual nessas `span` tags ?

```
var caixaTooltips = document.getElementById("banner-tooltips");
var tooltips = caixaTooltips.querySelectorAll("span");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode iterar todos os `span` e adicionar o evento `click`:

```
var caixaTooltips = document.getElementById("banner-tooltips");
var tooltips = caixaTooltips.querySelectorAll("span");

for (let i = 0 ; i < tooltips.length ; i++){
    tooltips[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log("Fui clicado: " + e);
    });
}
```